# how to make the query pick distinct values from a column as pivot values?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Query:

```
select employee_sk,
[201701],
[201702] 
 from

(select Employee_SK, Period_NK, CalcClinical_FTE  from cmgr.FACT_Payroll) as sourcetable

pivot
(
sum(CalcClinical_FTE)
for period_nk
in ([201701],[201702])
) as a
```

I have multiple periods in the period_nk column ranging from 201401 to 201801.
So, how can i assign the pivot values without having to write each column individually like 201701,201702, 201703...?

Comment: correct the tags this can't be a MySQL question because MySQL doesn't support PIVOT keyword. Seeing the brackets as column names i think you are using SQL-server.

Comment: The pivot command requires upfront knowledge of the physical columns to be pivoted. If you do not spell out the columns by hand then you have to resort to dynamic sql to pivot on the unknown columns.

Comment: so, there isn't a way to select all the distinct values as pivot columns other than using dynamic sql ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.period_nk) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT category, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select  category,
                        period_nk,
                        amount
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for period_nk in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

Output :

```
 category   201701  201702  201703  201704  201705
1   ABC 1000,0000   NULL    NULL    NULL    1100,0000
2   DEF NULL    500,0000    NULL    700,0000    NULL
3   GHI NULL    NULL    800,0000    NULL    NULL
```

[online demo](http://rextester.com/ERDYB6216)